# count and display distinct values in excel rows

Tags: excel, function, count, pivot, row

I have a table that looks like this

| name | column1 | column2 | column3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| name1 | a | b | b |
| name2 | c |  | a |
| name3 | a | a | dd |

I need to enter data in another table in this format:

name, label of the value, count occurances of value, label of the value, count occurances of value ...

| name | label | count | label | count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| name1 | a | 1 | b | 2 |
| name2 | c | 1 | a | 1 |
| name3 | a | 2 | dd | 1 |

I could copy data from the table1, if I could get it to list and display distinct values, somewhere in table1.

I tried using pivot table, but it expects data to be i columns, not in rows.

Is there any way this can be done in excel?

Thanks.

Comment: What about the 'a' in Name2, Column 3 - should that be ignored?

Comment: Right, fixed. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this by using the Data Model and creating measures to display text values within the Value field of a PivotTable, but I think Power Query would be more efficient.

- Load your data into Power Query.  Data tab in the Ribbon > From Table/Range
- Select the Name column, right-click, Unpivot Other Columns
- Select the Name and Value columns, right-click, Group By.
- New Column name = "Count", Operation = "Count Rows", Column will be blank.
- Select the Value and Count columns.  Go to the Transform tab in the ribbon, select Merge Columns under the Text Column section.  Use whatever seperator you want, I chose colon.
- Right-click the Name column, select Group By.  Name the column whatever you like, and do a Sum operation on your newly Merged column.

Your resulting column will have an error.  In the formula bar replace this code:

```
= Table.Group(#"Merged Columns", {"name"}, {{"MergedRows", each List.Sum([Merged]), type text}})
```

With this code, replacing MergedRows with your column header.

```
= Table.Group(#"Merged Columns", {"name"}, {{"MergedRows", each Text.Combine([Merged],":"), type text}})
```

- Notice how my Text.Combine separator is the same colon as I used earlier to merge columns.  Now you can selected your fully merged column, and choose Split Column under the Transform tab in the ribbon.  Choose delimiter and colon.
- Now you just need to clean up the column order and headers.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for an excellent answer.

One more question, is it possible to sort the result by label so it says
a 1, c 2
Instead of 
c 2, a 1.
I know it wasn't it the original question, sorry.

Thanks.

Comment: @user17014487 prior to doing the initial merge on the Value and Count columns sort the Value column ascending.

Answer (score -1):

Starting from Excel 2016 you can use the "Get & Transform" capabilities.

In short, select your data, then use the "From Table" button under Data | Get & Transform". A new Query Editor window opens, select the first column, right-click and select "Unpivot other columns": you get a table with a row for each combination of row/column in your original data range. You may want to change column headers, then just close the query editor and load the unpivoted data.

For more info have a look at [this article from Microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/blog/2015/12/15/learn-how-to-unpivot-static-tables-in-excel-2016/)

Comment: This process produces a three column table.  Doesn't look anything like the results table in the question.  Also, Power Query is available in Windows Excel 2010+ and also Office 365

Comment: But the OP said they thought to use a Pivot table (which btw won't look like the sample output anyhow)... so this process puts the data in a form suitable for pivoting. I don't know of other possibilities apart from using VBA. Also, although Power Query existed before, the Get & Transform integrated capability was a new feature of 2016 (and 365 of course).